# Breeze: cannot execute _executeQueryCore until metadataStore is populated

Tags: metadata, breeze, hottowel

I was using Breeze v1.1.2 that came with the Hot Towel template which has now been extended to form my project.  I made the mistake of updating the NuGet package to the current 1.3.3 (I never learn).  Anyway, all was well, and now not so much!

I followed the instructions in the release notes and other docs to change my BreezeWebApiConfig file to:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(
typeof(BreezeWebApiConfig), "RegisterBreezePreStart")]
namespace MyApp.App_Start {
public static class BreezeWebApiConfig {
    public static void RegisterBreezePreStart() {
      GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "BreezeApi",
          routeTemplate: "breeze/{controller}/{action}"
      );}}}
```

And the config.js file (which provides the serviceName to the EntityManager constructor) to:

```
var remoteServiceName = 'breeze/breeze';  // NEW version
//var remoteServiceName = 'api/breeze';  // OLD version
```

And my BreezeController if you're interested:

```
[BreezeController]
public class BreezeController : ApiController
{
    readonly EFContextProvider<MyDbContext> _contextProvider =
        new EFContextProvider<MyDbContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<SomeItem> SomeItems()
    {
        // Do stuff here...
    }
}
```

Now I get the "cannot execute _executeQueryCore until metadataStore is populated" error.

What am I missing here?

**EDIT:**
I perhaps left out the part you needed...  Above in the SomeItems() method, the stuff that actually gets done is a call to the GetMeSomeData() method in the MyDBContext class.  This method makes the following call to a stored procedure to get the data.

```
public virtual ObjectResult<SomeItem> GetMeSomeData(string inParam)
    {
        var p = new object[] { new SqlParameter("@inParam", inParam) };
        var retVal = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<SomeItem>("exec GetData @SN", p);
        return retVal;
    }
```

Now given my limited understanding, the call to Metadata() is not failing, but I don't think it has any idea what the entity model is when coming back, even though somewhere along the line, it should figure that out from the entity model I do have (i.e. SomeItem)?  The return string from Metadata() doesn't have any information about the entity.  Is there a way to make it aware?  Or am I just completely off in left field playing with the daisies?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say based on this report. Let's see if Breeze is right.

Open the browser debugging tools and look at the network traffic. Do you see an attempt to get metadata from the server before you get that error? If so, did it succeed? Or 404? Or 500? What was the error?

I'm betting it didn't even try. If it didn't, the usual reason is that you tried some Breeze operation before your first query ... and you didn't ask for metadata explicitly either. Did you try to create an entity? That requires metadata.

The point is, you've got to track down the Breeze operation that precipitates the error. Sure everything should just work. The world should be rainbows and unicorns. When it isn't, we heave a sigh, break out the debugger, and start with the information that the error gave us.

And for the rest of you out there ... upgrading to a new Breeze version is a good thing.

Happy coding everyone.

### Follow-up to your update

Breeze doesn't know how you get your data on the back-end. If the query result has a recognizable entity in it, Breeze will cache that. It's still up to you in the query callback to ensure that what you deliver to the caller is something meaningful.

You say that you're server-side metadata method doesn't have any idea what `SomeItem` is? Then it's not much use to the client. If it returns a null string, Breeze may treat that as "no metadata at all" in which case you should be getting the "cannot execute _executeQueryCore until metadataStore is populated" error message. Btw, did you check the network traffic to determine what your server actually returned in response to the metadata request (or if there was such a request)?

There are many ways to create Metadata on the server. The easiest is to use EF ... at least as a modeling tool at design time. What's in that `MyDbContext` of yours? Why isn't `SomeItem` in there?

You also can create metadata on the client if you don't want to generate it from the server. You do have to tell the Breeze client that you've made that choice. Much of this is explained in the documentation ["Metadata Format"](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-metadata-format).

I get the feeling that you're kind of winging it. You want to stray from the happy path ... and that's cool. But most of us need to learn to walk before we run.

Comment: I added some additional information above.  Any further thoughts?

Comment: I'm using EF5 and sprocs. I've read through _most_ of the Breeze docs, but don't see anything about this. You had stated it was doable [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173651/how-to-use-stored-procedure-that-accepts-paging-parameters) If I hand roll entity/DbContext, I get the error in the title of this post. If I use an emdx, I get 'could not find the CLR type for SomeItem'. All network traffic is 200 including metadata. SomeItem is in GetMeSomeData() as return type (ObjectResult), where the controller then returns .AsQuerable(). Unfortunately, I need to use sprocs and EF5.

Comment: The sproc is not the issue. The **lack of metadata** about `SomeItem` **is the issue**. No metadata, no go. It's good news that you get a 200 on your Metadata request before you ask the controller for `SomeItem`. What is in that metadata? Is `SomeItem` in there. If not, you have to takes steps. See [here for info on creating client-side metadata](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/breeze-metadata-format). You can also generate metadata on the server easily by using EF as a design tool but we'll hold on that. First ... do you have `SomeItem` in metadata or not? If not, try client-side def.

Comment: Works after creating client-side definition of `SomeItem` and setting `hasServerMetadata=false` (doesn't now call the `Metadata()` method). But, we are a data warehouse with 100's of sprocs that will need 100's of entities. I can't see having edmx function import create entities and then have to manually build them again in client side. I gather I'm missing something. :-(

Comment: On the server-side, are you pouring the results of your sproc calls into CLR classes? Or are you consuming the data raw? If you have CLR classes, you can generate metadata for them even if you cannot query the database for them in the usual EF manner. No point in my prattling on about this unless you confirm that you have a server-side model with CLR classes that corresponds to the output of your query sprocs.

Comment: I don't know how to answer that. The ADO.NET Entity Data Model automatically creates a complex object that matches the output of the sproc when I do a function import.  It would seem that it should put the results into a collection of those, but there is no metadata. On the SQL server, there are no CLR classes. This is old, generic sprocs that I have no control over. Would you mind sending me an email then I can reply with much more detail than I can on here, as we seemed to have moved away from the original topic of my post. Thank you for helping me! Send to dingored123 at hot mail.

Comment: We're straying beyond the bounds of free support with this comparatively exotic model. We (IdeaBlade) offer paid support and professional services for folks who need advanced help like this ... that's how we fund Breeze. But I'll send you an email and we can see if there is something more I can do ... or if you want to engage our services. No promises of course.