# Breeze: Directly transmit/append OData to query

Tags: javascript, odata, breeze

I'm trying to use OData functions which should be working (for example `cast`) but breeze seems to parse a query before even sending it over the wire.

I found the following map of functions in breeze's code and it seems to me, that breeze is limited to those functions - no matter what my OData-Version would support:

- toupper
- tolower
- substring
- substringof
- length
- trim
- concat
- replace
- startswith
- endswith
- indexof
- round
- ceiling
- floor
- second
- minute
- day
- month
- year

Appart from this restriction I've been asking myself, if it's possible to extend a normal breeze query with some custom OData string. Something like:

```
breeze.EntityQuery.from("My_Resource").where("MyProperty", "==", 1).appendOData('$top=200');
```

Now - I know that `$top` can be done with breeze - it's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read this answer:

[How to use Stored Procedure that accepts Paging Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173651/how-to-use-stored-procedure-that-accepts-paging-parameters/41429737#41429737)

It shows how to completely manipulate a breeze oData request, and you can even render the SQL before you send it.  It's worth a look.

I haven't tried changing the options object, then rendering the SQL but I know it can be done.

Comment: I did not find anything related to my question in your other SO answer. Could you explain briefly what you meant? Especially, I'm talking here about the client-side breezeJS-query and in your answer you talk about manipulating the request on the server-side...